# Mockito.mock is not working, using Mockito.when causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, mockito

I have used Mockito very long time. With Mockito 4.7.0 version (and also for example with the version 3.12.4) the code:

```
A a = mock(A.class);
when(a.doX()).thenReturn("X");
```

causes the `java.lang.NullPointerException` in the second line.

When I print the content of the variable `a`

```
System.out.println(a);
```

I got also "java.lang.NullPointerException".

For any other class the `Mockito.mock` and `Mockito.when` are working perfectly and if I print a content of some other class instance `b` I got "Mock for B, hashcode: some hash code"

Do you know what could be problem? My example is simplified and I can't show the actual classes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My service test fails when I have an if statement in the class under test SpringBoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73743671/my-service-test-fails-when-i-have-an-if-statement-in-the-class-under-test-spring)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your code, but I tried to be the more generic as I can.
I have test like the one below and it works great.
Hope to been helpful.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyTest {

    @Mock
    private AClass aclass;

    @Mock
    private BClass bclass;

    @Mock
    private CClass cclass;

    @Test
    void testExecute() {
        
        when(aclass.getAbc(any(String.class), any(Date.class), anyString()))
            .thenAnswer(i -> getAbc(i.getArgument(0), i.getArgument(1), i.getArgument(2)));

        when(bclass.isOk())
            .thenAnswer(i -> false);

        when(cclass.getCdf(anyString()))
            .thenAnswer(i -> getCdf());
        ...
        ...
        ...

    }

    private List<ABC> getAbc(final String myString, final Date now, final String x) {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }

    private CDF getCdf() {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }

}
```

As you can see, for a simple answer I write the answer directly, for a more complex one, I create a private method with the same name and use it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will still call the real method, unless `A` is an interface. I assume it is an implementation (a class) in your code.

```
A a = mock(A.class);
when(a.doX()).thenReturn("X");
//   ^^^^^^^-- this is calling the real method
```

If you must use the class and cannot switch to an interface, you have do use `Mockito.doReturn` instead of `Mockito.when`:

```
A a = mock(A.class);
doReturn("X").when(a).doX();
```

But it is probably better to extract an interface and create mocks from the interface, not by subclassing your real class.